# Flex: Custom Menu Functionality

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

Does anyone know of a way to keep a menu open after clicking one of its menu items?  I have a custom menu (extended the menu object) it contains a bunch of ‘check’ type menu items, the requirement I am trying to fulfill is to allow the user to click multiple menu items without the menu closing, and then have the menu close when it loses focus, is this possible? If it is can someone please explain how it can be done (pref. with a small example).

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

You should listen to the itemClick event and call preventDefault() on your menu handler.

```
private function menuItemClick(evt:MenuEvent):void
{
    // set your checks
    evt.preventDefault();
}
```